# Azure Marketplace Landing Page throws exception when used with Visual Studio 2022 tunnelling

Tags: c#, .net, azure, marketplace

I've a small C# application project based on WebAPI with Razor pages and .NET 8.0. It should just serve as a small application to manage the landing page for the users that sign on our MS Azure Marketplace. The setup code is the following:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Startup startup = new(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureService(builder.Services);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
    //MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
    //HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

....
....
....

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Configure AAD and Graph integration
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration!)//Sign on with Azure ADD
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })//Calls Graph API
            .AddMicrosoftGraph()//Use default with Graph v1
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();//Add token caching

        //Configure OpenIDConnect
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
            options => options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect =
            context =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
                context.HandleResponse();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        );

        //Validate JWT attributes
        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            options => {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = this.Configuration["MarketplaceApi:ClientId"];
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{this.Configuration["MarketplaceApi:TenantId"]}";                    
            });

        //Add the marketplace service
        ConfigureMarketplaceServices(services);

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));                
        });

        services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddDbContext<AzureMarketplaceDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:AzureMarketplaceMSSql"));
    }

    private void ConfigureMarketplaceServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var tenantId = Configuration["MarketplaceApi:TenantId"];
        var clientId = Configuration["MarketplaceApi:ClientId"];
        var clientSecret = Configuration["MarketplaceApi:ClientSecret"];

        //Standards Azure credentials
        var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        //CReates MarketplaceSaaSClient object to be injected
        services.TryAddScoped<IMarketplaceSaaSClient>(sp =>
        {
            return new MarketplaceSaaSClient(credentials);
        });            
    }
}
```

When I run in debug the application locally it correctly opens the login page where I can sign in without any issue. But if I try to run it using Visual Studio 2022 tunnelling in order to see if the landing page is correctly called from MS Azure, I get the following exception immediately after logging in:

[image]

And the log shows the following errors:

[image]

Is there anyone that has an idea on how to fix it ? Thank you in advance.

**** UPDATE *****

Configuration file (appsettings.json):

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "MyCompany.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "ClientSecret": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
  "MarketplaceApi": {
    "ClientId": "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "ClientSecret": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureMarketplaceMSSql": "Server=ssssssssss;Database=jjjjjjjjjjjj;User ID=sa;Password=kkkkkkkkkkkk;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**** BROWSER ERROR ****

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AuthenticationFailureException: Correlation failed.
Unknown location

AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Correlation failed.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Correlation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**** LOG FILE ERROR ****

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]
'.AspNetCore.Correlation.zoY7cLioLI9dUlmbF94ZwZvXNx2o8kl8ih9hurzCyd4' cookie not found.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnftb.png)
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Correlation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Can you please share your configuration file by masking the values

Comment: Why do you need Startup file.You can configure it in `Program.cs` file itself.Also share the error in text format.

Comment: The code has been split in 2 classes just for convenience, no other reason. I've added what you requested. Thank you